# Scrapy Splash shows loading on webpage

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to crawl [this page](https://www.flipkart.com/nokia-6-silver-32-gb/product-reviews/itmevt7zhgbpuveq?pid=MOBEVR8XPGV6SJFX)
But the page is stuck on loading.

I'm using 
Scrapy==1.5.0
scrapy-splash==0.7.2

I even changed the wait time to 7 seconds. but the problem persists. Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the wait_for_element lua script to ensure the html you're after  is loaded. It might take longer than 7 seconds, but at least it will have the element loaded without needing a fixed timeout. Splash can take longer than a regular web browser to load the page.

https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/splash/examples/wait-for-element.lua